# Change the format of a value

Tags: vb.net

I have this problem where I have a listbox with the items the client has ordered and the total on top ,I also have a button that opens a panel that lets me set a % to discount from the total value.
The problem is that the outcome is not in the right format, im very new to this so its harder for me, the total ends up being very different
In this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC8xi.png) i have the total 10,15 and want 10% discount and it gave me 913,49994.
Can someone fix this please?
Best regards.
This is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim Total
    Public Sub BtnConta_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnConta.Click
        ' Specify the file path where you want to save the ListBox items
        Dim filePath As String = "C:\Mesa1.txt"

        ' Open the file for writing
        Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
            ' Loop through each item in the ListBox
            For Each item As Object In ListBoxConsumo.Items
                ' Write the item to the file
                writer.WriteLine(item.ToString())
            Next
        End Using

        MessageBox.Show("ListBox items saved to file.")

        Dim quoteArray As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Mesa1.txt")
        For Each Item As String In quoteArray

            Dim parts As String() = Strings.Split(Item, "€__")
            Dim number As Decimal
            If Decimal.TryParse(parts(0), number) Then

            End If



            Total = (Total + number)
        Next
        TxtBoxTotal.Text = Total




    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnDesconto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDesconto.Click
        PanelDesconto.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListBoxConsumo.Items.Add("1,45€__Pão")
    End Sub



    Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        Dim loc As Integer
        loc = TextBoxTeclado1.Text.Length
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = TextBoxTeclado1.Text.Remove(loc - 1, 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click

        Dim percentagem As Single


        If IsNumeric(TextBoxTeclado1.Text) Then
            percentagem = CDbl(TextBoxTeclado1.Text)
        Else
            percentagem = 0 ' No discount
        End If

        If percentagem < 100 Then
            Total = Total * (100 - percentagem)
        Else
            ' Item is free
            Total = 0
        End If

        MsgBox(Total)


    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSair_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSair.Click
        PanelDesconto.Hide()
    End Sub



    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 2

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 3

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 4

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 5

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 6

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 7

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 8

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 9

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 0

    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Specify the file path from where you want to load the contents
        Dim filePath As String = "C:\Mesa1.txt"

        ' Check if the file exists
        If File.Exists(filePath) Then
            ' Read all lines from the file
            Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Mesa1.txt")

            ' Clear the existing items in the ListBox
            ListBoxConsumo.Items.Clear()

            ' Add each line to the ListBox
            For Each line As String In lines
                ListBoxConsumo.Items.Add(line)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub



End Class
```

Mesa.txt :

1,45€__Pão
1,45€__Pão
1,45€__Pão
1,45€__Pão
1,45€__Pão
1,45€__Pão
1,45€__Pão
1.45€__Pão

watched many videos but couldnt find a fix

Comment: please add mesa.txt, so that we can test your code

Comment: The math in line `Total = Total * (100 - percentagem)` is just plain wrong sorry.  As is you're just multiplying the total by 100 - the discount percent (90 in this case).  Maybe something like `Total = Total * (1 - (percentagem/100))` might work better for you.

Comment: this textfile is just 
"1,45€__Pão" in each line

Comment: wow @Hursey it worked, it gave me 9,134999,  is there a way to remove the "4999" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not converting the discount percentage to a decimal before you use it in the calculation.
Change **Button13_Click** to :

```
Dim percentagem As Decimal

If IsNumeric(TextBoxTeclado1.Text) Then
    percentagem = CDbl(TextBoxTeclado1.Text) / 100
Else
    percentagem = 0 ' No discount
End If

If percentagem < 100 Then
    Total = Total * (1 - percentagem)
Else
    ' Item is free
    Total = 0
End If

Total = Math.Round(Total, 0)
```

This code will first convert the discount percentage to a decimal by dividing it by 100. Then, it will use the decimal value in the calculation.

Let me know how it's going.
I don't have the VS IDE. Maybe there is a syntax problem.

Comment: It Worked out great, it gave me 9,135, is there a way to take the 5 out?

Comment: You can use the Truncate function to remove the decimal places from the discounted price. add bellow line after end of last End If:
Total = Truncate(Total)

Comment: Take care truncating. You may need to round up instead.

Comment: Total = Truncate(Total) said  Truncate isnt declared, how can i round up?

Comment: Try: Total = Round(Total, 0) (Truncate should be in Math library)

Comment: not declared either

Comment: what is math library

Comment: "Round" is a system library. Did you import "System"? I see now, change "Import System.IO" to "Import System." I think that's the correct approach.

Comment: I put both imports, if i dont i have errors where it says "file", neither round or truncate work

Comment: Did you try Math.Round ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.round?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Decimal_Round_System_Decimal_System_Int32_